# How to send float[] via UDP + Unsigned-Long-Operator-Curiosity

Tags: c++, udp, char, sendto

I am writing an C++ Application which reads several voltages from a device. I receive these measurements in an `float[]` and I want to send this array via UDP to a MATLAB-Script.

the C++-function sendto needs to get an `char[]` buffer and I really have no idea how to convert the `float[]` into a `char[]` buffer so i can reassemble it easily in MATLAB. Any Ideas?

Another problem i encountered is that line

```
addr.sin_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

inet_addr returns an unsigned long, but my compiler tells me that the = operator does not accept an unsigend long datatype on its right side. Any Iideas about this?

Comment: Instead of `inet_addr()`, use `inet_aton()` and pass the address of `addr.sin_addr` as the second argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always treat any object variable as a sequence of bytes. For this very purpose, it is explicitly allowed (and does not violate aliasing or constitute type punning) to reinterpret any object pointer as a pointer to the first element in an array of bytes (i.e. any `char` type).

**Example:**

```
T x;
char const * p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(&x);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i != sizeof x; ++i) { /* p[i] is the ith byte in x */ }
```

**For your case:**

```
float data[N];
char const * p = reinterpret_cast<char const *>(data);

write(fd, p, sizeof data);
```

Comment: To use this method, the receiver must know the float representation that the sender is using.

Comment: @ShaunMarko: I want to say that that's the problem of the other side that does the `read` operation ;-)

Comment: If both sender and receiver understand IEEE 754 then there's no problem.

Comment: Of course the sender and receiver must agree on the representation of the data being transmitted. The point is that a receiver should not naively think that `float data[N]; char *p(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data); read(fd, p, sizeof(data));` is necessarily going to work with a sender that uses the code in this answer. The representation of float values in C++ is implemtation-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Decide if you want to format the UDP messages as text or binary. If text, you can convert floats to strings using boost::lexical_cast. You can frame the string valus in the UDP message any way you want (comma separated values, newline separated, etc.), or you could use a known format such as JSON.

If you want to transmit binary data, select an known format, such as XDR which is used by ONC RPC and use existing library tools to create the binary messages.

As for the inet_addr error, addr.sin_addr is a struct in_addr. You need to assign the result to the s_addr member of the sin_addr struture like this:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions in your post. I believe that is not how it's supposed to be.

As for float[]->byte[] conersion - you should check how matlab stores it's floating point variables. If, by any chance, it uses the same format as you compiler, for your computer setup etc etc only, you can simply send these as a byte array[]. In any other case - incompatible float byte format, multiple machines - you have to write a manual conversion. First each float to (for example) string, then many floats. Your line could look like:

`1.41234;1.63756;456345.45634`

As for the addr.sin_addr  - I think you are doing it wrong. You should access

`addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("1.1.1.1");`

Comment: Single precision floating point (and double precision, for that matter) is standardized in IEEE 754-1985 resp -2008, and Matlab adheres to this standard. Yes, you may have to account for endianness between different machines, but apart from that you're fine. Your suggestion of a string conversion seems unnecessarily inefficient and error-prone.